# Synthesis without meta-analysis, z-score for 2 proportions?

Tags: meta-analysis, clinical-trials

I am doing a meta-analysis. One of the outcomes I meta-analyzed involved pooling multiple types of related complications. There wasn't enough data to pool the individual reasons for the complications, but I still wanted to do some synthesis with that data as it gives clinically relevant information on why we we may be seeing the differences.

This is an example of a table I want to include. Would it be valid to do a Z-score for proportions and assess if there is a difference in the proportion between group 1 and group 2 for each reason? Or would this be not methodologically sound as then i am not appropriately weighing studies.

I read the relevant cochrane handbook chapter, but I couldn't find an answer. I would really appreciate any thoughts.

[image]

Comment: Are they mutually exclusive? If so then just collapse over reason.